# Filter products by clickable value in custom column WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

We add a new column to display the author => store-name form each product. ([Add custom meta column to WooCommerce product listing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65944020/add-custom-meta-column-to-woocommerce-product-listing))

I was able to answer the mentioned question by my self. But now we ran into a new problem. The needed information are now in the new column, but we can not click it. We want to have the entries in that new column clickable in order that every product from that author would be filtered. So it's a question about how to make a clickable link in order to show all other product from that author.

This is our code:

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-product_columns', 'custom_admin_products_store_name_column', 9999 );
 
function custom_admin_products_store_name_column( $columns ){
   $columns['vendor_store_name'] = __( 'Vendor'); 
   return $columns;
}
 
add_action( 'manage_product_posts_custom_column', 'custom_admin_products_store_name_column_content', 10, 2 );
 
function custom_admin_products_store_name_column_content( $column, $product_id ){

    $seller = get_post_field( 'post_author', $product_id);
    $store_info = dokan_get_store_info( $seller );
    $store_name = $store_info['store_name'];

    if ( $column == 'vendor_store_name' ) {
        echo __($store_name);
        
    }
}
```

I already tried around with the information from here: [WooCommerce: Adding a custom filter to the Product Admin area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34135816/woocommerce-adding-a-custom-filter-to-the-product-admin-area)

But this is more for a new filter than a clickable value in a column which will apply a filter.

Comment: _“But this is more for a new filter than a clickable value in a column which will apply a filter.”_ - the part of _applying_ the filter should still be pretty much the same. Only the first part is different - there it uses a `select` field set up in one location, to pass the value to filter by as a GET parameter - you want to do it with individual links instead. So, create those links, and have them include the necessary GET parameter.

Comment: The link for the filter would be /wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=product&author= at the end I need the ID. I will try this now! :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work! :)

Here is my code. Is this a proper solution or where can I improve this? :)

Thanlks

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-product_columns', 'custom_admin_products_store_name_column', 9999 );
 
function custom_admin_products_store_name_column( $columns ){
   $columns['vendor_store_name'] = __( 'Vendor'); 
   return $columns;
}
 
add_action( 'manage_product_posts_custom_column', 'custom_admin_products_store_name_column_content', 10, 2 );
 
function custom_admin_products_store_name_column_content( $column, $product_id ){

    $seller = get_post_field( 'post_author', $product_id);
    $store_info = dokan_get_store_info( $seller );
    $store_name = $store_info['store_name'];
    
$vendor_products = get_admin_url() . 'edit.php?post_type=product&author=' . $seller;

if ( $column == 'vendor_store_name' ) {
        printf('<a href="%s">%s</a>', $vendor_products, $store_name);       
}
    

}
```